# npm install runs correctly, but cannot run topojson

Tags: npm

If I do:

```
npm init
npm install --save topojson
```

I end up with a package.json file and `node_modules` directory, all looking correct. But if I then do:

```
topojson
```

I see:

```
-bash: topojson: command not found
```

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use package installed locally in node\_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

Comment: The solution there doesn't work - if I do `$ ls ./node_modules/.bin/` I see various modules but not `topojson`. So not a duplicate, I assume.

Comment: It seems that the `topojson` package does not register a `topojson` binary. It does yield `geo2topo`, `toposimplify`, `topo2geo`, `topomerge`, and `topoquantize`.

Comment: Ah I think this might have something to do with it...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462775/topojson-command-not-added-on-npm-install#comment82532432_47462775 No idea what I'm actually supposed to install though, `npm install topojson-client` doesn't get `topojson` or `topojson-client` running either and there's nothing in the docs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue turned out not to be related to npm - `npm install topojson` no longer installs a command-line tool called `topojson`. Confusingly, [it used to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462775/topojson-command-not-added-on-npm-install#comment82532432_47462775), but the package has changed.

Answer (score -1):

try this step

install globally using `-g`

```
 1. install nodejs http://nodejs.org/
 2. install npm https://npmjs.org/doc/README.html
 3. run npm install -g topojson in your command prompt
 4. use the command prompt to cd to the geojson file
 5. run topojson -o myNewTopojsonFile.json myOldGeojsonFile.json
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like to run it locally!